# Get data from HttpServletRequest with spring mvc

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC.

What I want to achieve is to add a map of data into HttpServletRequest;
Example:

```
private NewRequestService newRequest = new NewRequestService();

public ModelAndView inputRequiredInfo(@ModelAttribute("requestForm") HttpServletRequest request) {
  request.setAttribute("mylist", newRequest.loadAllUserDomainType());

  return new ModelAndView("request/selectDomainUser","requestForm", request);

}
```

And then in the view jsp file, I want to get those data which pass into the request and put it into dropdown list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forget what you've done right now.

There are two ways from a `@Controller` handler methods to make attributes available to a JSP.

1. Make your method accept an `HttpServletRequest` parameter and set the target object as a request attribute directly.
2. Make your method accept a `Model`, `ModelMap`, `ModelAndView`, or `Map` parameter and set the target object as a request attribute on that `Model` argument. You can also make your method return any of the above.

For `2.`, Spring will take the elements you added to the `Model` and put them into the `HttpServletRequest` attributes. They will then be available while rendering the JSP.

Let's have some examples:

Return a `ModelAndView` with one attribute

```
public ModelAndView inputRequiredInfo() {
    Map map = newRequest.loadAllUserDomainType();

    return new ModelAndView("request/selectDomainUser","mylist", map);
}
```

Return a `ModelAndView` with no attributes, but add the attribute directly to `HttpServletRequest`

```
public ModelAndView inputRequiredInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map map = newRequest.loadAllUserDomainType();
    request.setAttribute("mylist", map);
    return new ModelAndView("request/selectDomainUser");
}
```

Return a `String` view name but add attributes to a `Model` passed as argument

```
public String inputRequiredInfo(Model model) {
    Map map = newRequest.loadAllUserDomainType();
    model.addAttribute("mylist", map);
    return "request/selectDomainUser";
}
```

In the above example, you could have passed `Model`, `ModelMap`, or `java.util.Map`.

Same but with `HttpServletRequest`

```
public String inputRequiredInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map map = newRequest.loadAllUserDomainType();
    request.setAttribute("mylist", map);
    return "request/selectDomainUser";
}
```

For a more complete list of accepted method arguments, see [section 17.3.3 of the official documentation.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) While you are at it, also read the supported return types to understand the difference between returning a `ModelAndView` and returning a `String`.

Answer (score -2):

This is not the correct way though.

You can use something like a model attribute.

Check the links below for a lot of answers on this:

[How to pass model attributes from one Spring MVC controller to another controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429649/how-to-pass-model-attributes-from-one-spring-mvc-controller-to-another-controlle)

[Passing parameters from JSP to Controller in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590036/passing-parameters-from-jsp-to-controller-in-spring-mvc)