# How to send el value to spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi I am able to display value from spring controller in jsp using Expression language like

```
{msg}
```

How to do I send back this value to spring controller without form tag

Comment: By making the user click on a link. Or posting a form. Or by sending an AJAX request using JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters from JSP to Controller in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590036/passing-parameters-from-jsp-to-controller-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: is it possible to send any url tag like c:url

Comment: c:url is used to generate a URL and write the result string to the HTTP response stream. What are you actually trying to achieve? Sending a tag to a controller doesn't mean anything. You send HTTP requests to a controller.

Comment: I just want {msg} value from jsp to controller without form tag

Comment: It depends on when you want to send this value like 'button click event' or 'page load'. If possible, please add your related code so that we can help more accurately.

Answer (score -1):

public String someAction(@RequestParam("someid") String id)
{

}

Comment: JSP:
input name= id  
controller:
can also use @RequestParam string id